# How to set ExportOptions for custom HTML exports

Tags: front-end, export, html

I need to customize some HTML tags when exporting a *Mathematica* notebook to HTML. I have to use the [`File ► Save As…`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/SaveAs.html) FrontEnd token and not `Export` for some other reasons. So, to make a basic example, this is something that works fine:

```
Export["test.html", EvaluationNotebook[], "HTML", 
 "ConversionRules" -> {"ItemNumbered" -> {"<li>", "</li>"}, 
   "Text" -> {"<p class=\"mytext\">", "</p>"}}]
```

Now, I have seen that at FrontEnd level there is an option named `ConversionOptions` that includes `"ExportOptions"`, that again includes `"ConversionRules"`. So I'm trying to set such option, by means of the [Option Inspector](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/OptionInspector.html) or by `SetOptions`, so to have the following

```
    ConversionOptions->{"ExportOptions"->{
 "HTML" -> {"ConversionRules" -> {"ItemNumbered" -> {"<li>", "</li>"}, "Text" -> {"<p class=\"mytext\">", "</p>"}}, 
    "GraphicsOutput"->"PNG", "MathOutput" -> "PNG", "ConvertClosed" -> False, "ConvertReverseClosed" -> 
    False, "ConvertLinkedNotebooks" -> False, "Content" -> False, 
    "CSSInclude" -> True, "CSSRadio" -> False}}}
```

Unfortunately using `File ► Save As…` does nothing of what I added into the `ConversionOptions`. Where I have to set my own export options for HTML?

Answer (score 5):

Finally, after many attempts, I had the answer: the `ConversionOptions` have to be assigned to `"XHTML"` and not to `"HTML"`. Indeed, this works:

```
ConversionOptions->{
  "ExportOptions"->{"XHTML" -> {"ConversionRules" -> {"ItemNumbered" -> 
            {"<li>", "</li>"}, "Text" -> {"<p class=\"mytext\">", "</p>"}}, 
            "GraphicsOutput"->"PNG", "MathOutput" -> "PNG",
            "ConvertClosed" -> False, "ConvertReverseClosed" -> False, 
            "ConvertLinkedNotebooks" -> False, "Content" -> False, 
            "CSSInclude" -> True, "CSSRadio" -> False}}}
```

This is very funny, documentation and all examples (really few, has to be said) set `"HTML"` `ConversionRules` when using it inside `Export`, but if you need to set it at FrontEnd level you have to assign it to `"XHTML"`. However, at last it works!

Comment: Daily fun with MMA :) please consider reporting this to WRI.