# "Most compatible vector representation"

Tags: front-end, export

When saving a plot through `right click ► Save Graphic As…`, *Mathematica* lets me choose several options, including separate vector representations for areas with transparency and with smooth shading. In particular, in addition to using a rasterized or high-quality vector version, it has an option to "use most compatible vector representation".

How can I do this using `Export`? Saving through right click introduces weird glitches in the labels and I want to be able to save the graphics manually, but I end up with either ugly rasterized images or 80-megabyte monstrosities. The "most compatible vector representation" seems to have a great file size to quality ratio.

Comment: The .NB files with implementations of the export options dialogs are located in the folder `FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources"}]`. For example, the "PDF Options" dialog is in the file `ExportPDF.nb`. You can open it in a text editor and inspect the implementation.

Comment: It seems that these Dialogs modify the `ConversionOptions` settings of the FrontEnd. According to [the Documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConversionOptions.html), before version 6 this option was recognized by `Export`, but currently it is obsolete and `Export` doesn't accept it anymore. So now it is an undocumented FrontEnd option.

Comment: Related: "[How to set ExportOptions for custom HTML exports](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81174/280)."

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Thanks a lot, this definitely answers my question (although leaves me a bit disappointed!) so feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NB files with implementations of the FrontEnd export options Dialogs are located in the folder

```
FileNameJoin[{$InstallationDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "SystemResources"}]
```

For example, the "PDF Options" Dialog is in the file "ExportPDF.nb". You can open it with a text editor and inspect the implementation.

From the internals of the "ExportPDF.nb" file I conclude that this Dialog modifies the `ConversionOptions` settings of the FrontEnd. According to [the Documentation‌](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConversionOptions.html)​, before version 6 this option was recognized by `Export` but currently it is obsolete, and `Export` doesn't accept it anymore. So now it is an undocumented FrontEnd option.

However [these Q&A](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81174/280) give a *hope* that `Export` and the `Save Graphic As…` FrontEnd token aren't independent from each other and there *may* exist a way to pass some of the undocumented `ConversionOptions` suboptions to `Export`. Unfortunately at the moment I can't say anything more encouraging: all this stuff is a truly dark area...