# How to change Export default in 11.2?

Tags: export, csv-format

To achieve the same CSV output as from previous versions `Export` requires the option `"TextDelimiters" -> ""`.  Presumably the default has been changed.  Can I change the default back so I don't have to modify code or type in the option every time?

*Demonstration code - does not need the option in 11.1*

```
data = {
   {"", "Marmalade", "Rocket Science"},
   {"", "899-01-4862", "32432342324"},
   {"31/12/2017", "", "3428.762324"}};
out = "test.csv";
Export[out, data, "TextDelimiters" -> ""];
in = ReadList[out, Word, WordSeparators -> {","},
   RecordLists -> True, RecordSeparators -> {"\n"},
   NullWords -> True];
data == in
```

> True

**Note**

One reason for wanting to retain the previous export behaviour is for working with CSVs in both Mathematica and Excel.  To explain, opening either CSV outputs below in Excel and saving will result in Output 1 format.  So for diffing CSVs and using a predictable input format the Output 1 format is preferable.

[image]

**A further discovery**

When writing a CSV Excel and previous versions of Mathematica put strings with commas in quotes.  Use of `"TextDelimiters" -> ""` knocks out this functionality.

```
data = {
   {"Q", "IBM, Plc", "Rocket Science"},
   {"", "899-01-4862", "32432342324"},
   {"31/12/2017", "123,456,789.76", "3428.762324"}};
Export["test.csv", data]
```

[image]

Comment: I can't find anything for setting the default options for exporting.  The only thing I can think is to find the internal function from the ```System`Convert`*``` context and use SetOptions on it.  It wouldn't stick across kernel sessions though, so you would have to do that in your init.m file

Comment: this seems relevant, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81174/9490, though I can't find anything that works there

Comment: @JasonB. the function is ``System`Convert`TableDump`ExportSV``. You'll need ``System`ConvertersDump`LoadExportFormat["CSV"]`` first. It may have some autoload trigger on it too, because at first I couldn't see its options.

Comment: @b3m2a1 You found the right function.  Along with caveats about using internal functions Wolfram support said to evaluate `ExportString[{1}, "CSV"];(*can't set the option without autoloading*)
SetOptions[System`Convert`TableDump`ExportSV, "TextDelimiters" -> ""]
`